# Add calendar to iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, calendar

I am currently making and iphone app and a big function that i want to incorporate is the ability to subscribe to a calendar..
what i wish to do is to let the user give a URL for where the calendar is held, and from that url i want the app to fetch that calendar and subscribe to it..

i want to know how i can write the code to do this..

so in short my question is..

what code would i write to:

1. get .ics file from a URL
2. and save/subscribe to this newly
   fetched .ics calendar file

any help and info would be very much appreciated..

Comment: You can try this other answer as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597051/how-to-programmatically-add-calendar-subscriptions-on-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of "subscribing" to something isn't a build in function of the iOS SDK. To get this type of functionality would mean writing a recurring/timed function to grab the contents of this URL and process it locally.

The library I often use to simplify some of the HTTP functionality that you'll need is asi-http-request

https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. i will try this route and see what i come up with.. :)