# How to programmatically add calendar subscriptions on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, calendar, eventkit

Via the settings panel of your iPhone, you can add a subscription to a remote .ics calendar format. I have [a Dutch iPhone app](http://appshopper.com/productivity/feestdagen-2010-2011) that does this from within the app (see the screenshot below, "abonneren op de agenda" means "subscribe to the calendar"), but there must be others too.

I want to mimic this behavior for a project of mine, but I can't find the API to do this with. It looks like it's not a part of EventKit, but because there's no app switching going on when you hit 'subscribe' in the example app I suspect it's also not a url scheme.

Who knows?

[image: Existing app]
[image: Subscriptions in the mail settings panel]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
NSString *url = @"http://server/filename.ics";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

This shows an uialertview with the question to the user if he/she wants to subscribe.

;)

Comment: Great suggestion, stranger :P

Comment: I had trouble getting the alert to appear. Instead it showed a list of events that it wanted to add.

I changed the scheme name from http:// to webcal:// and was able to subscribe.

Comment: What if my ics file is protected with http authentication method. Where to provide username and password?

Comment: Can you use something like this?

`NSString *url = @"http://username:password@server/filename.ics";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];`

Comment: Does this open Calendar directly ? Generally URL's are opened in Safari rite. How does iOS differentiate if this particular URL has to be sent to iCal ? Does it recognize .ics at the end ?

Comment: I tested this in my App, it opens Safari first and then goes to Calendar.