# objective c - how can i open ics files on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, calendar, icalendar

I have built an app for week numbers, and I have made an ics file with week numbers in, but how can I open it with Objective-C so it will subscribe into calender?

I can't figure out how I can do this. Are there any frameworks I can use, or what?

I have tried:

```
NSString *ical = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:
                 [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxxxxxx.xx/apps-iphone/weeknumber/ical/ical.ics"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

but I can open it with that.

It needs to look like this:

[image]

Hope you understand me. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretending that you have the .ics file inside your app, right? And with this .ics file you want to open the Safari and have the alert?

Take a look at [EventKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) framework. You can integrate your app with the user's calendar. From EventKit's programming guide:

> Event Kit not only allows your app to retrieve users’ existing
>   calendar and reminder data, but it also lets your app create new
>   events and reminders for any of their calendars. In addition, Event
>   Kit lets users edit and delete their events and reminders
>   (collectively known as “calendar items”). More advanced tasks, such as
>   adding alarms or specifying recurring events, can be achieved with
>   Event Kit as well. If a change to the Calendar database occurs from
>   outside of your app, Event Kit is able to detect the change by
>   notification so your app can act appropriately. Changes made to
>   calendar items with Event Kit are automatically synced to the
>   associated calendar (CalDAV, Exchange, and so on).

As an alternative, you can open it using this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://addressToYourics.ics"]];
```

But, unfortunately, you can't open bundle files with Safari, so I suggest you to use the EventKit library.

Take a look at another questions:
[Is there a calendar control we can use for iPhone apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634000/is-there-a-calendar-control-we-can-use-for-iphone-apps)
[How to programmatically add calendar subscriptions on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597051/how-to-programmatically-add-calendar-subscriptions-on-ios)

Comment: That's great, @KasperBasse! If it worked to you, [mark the answer as right](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png). :)