# Programmatically subscribe to an external .ics Calendar on Android

Tags: android, icalendar, android-calendar

I'd like to have a button in my app that when pressed will have a user start the process of subscribing to my external .ics calendar, [similar to what this post shows how to do for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597051/how-to-programmatically-add-calendar-subscriptions-on-ios). Is there a way to do something like this on Android?

Comment: did you find a way to do this ?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not

Comment: @MohamedHafez Do you have some update on this, for example is it passible to subscribe native Google-Calendar installed on the device for some another via service end-point like in the IOS and to see another calendar's events in the native calendar?