# How to programmatically add calendar subscriptions on Android?

Tags: android, calendar, icalendar

Does anybody happen to know how to subscribe to a server-hosted iCal calendar (such as `http://server/filename.ics`) from an Android device programmatically?

So far I've seen this is possible manually using calendar.google.com and then go to "Other Calendars", "Add by URL".

On iOS it is possible subscribing to the server-hosted iCal calendar according to: [How to programmatically add calendar subscriptions on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597051/how-to-programmatically-add-calendar-subscriptions-on-ios)

Comment: do you guy have any solution for this problem yet?